# {solved} iOS / Swift: adapt height of WKWebview programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I need to adapt the height of a WKWebview programmatically and tried the following:

```
var newFrame = webView.frame
newFrame.size.height = 100
webView.frame = newFrame
```

The webview is generated as follows:

```
var webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect( x: 0,
                                       y:        safeArea_top,
                                       width:    view.frame.width,
                                       height:   view.frame.height), 
                         configuration: webConfiguration)
```

Unfortunately, there is no impact on the height at all (the original height is 896, so the impact should be significant).

SOLVED: I forgot to remove some constraints that were added programmatically... So everything works. Sorry for the noise :-(

Comment: Where does the original height come from? Do you have constraints set?

Comment: no constraints... I added the code how the webview is created

Comment: I replicated your problem in a playground (https://gist.github.com/Sparkier/94872071acd7e417ad725822f2396e6a), and this seems to work fine. I think we need more information to help you.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code snippet for us to try our your exact problem?

Comment: I tried your example on github, but it did not work :-( 

What do you need/would be helpful?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There were some constraints I added programmatically (were somehow hidden)

Comment: No problem, just added this hint as an answer, so people immediately see what the solution was.

Comment: @Andreas how do you remove the constraints? where are they?

Answer (score 0):

I generally find the following is better for defining a WKWebview.

```
var webView: WKWebView?

webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())

self.view.addSubview(webView!)
```

Comment: correct... I added the WKWebView as you proposed...  But the issue is: How to change the height... afterwards?

Comment: Have you tried updating the view after with `setNeedsDisplay()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check for constraints, those might be preventing your view from resizing.